# How to compose JS functions with condition check at each step?

Tags: javascript

I have written my code

```
function takesst(str) {
  const str1 = [...str];
  const l = str1.length;
  const check = (str1) => (str1.indexOf('(') === 0 && str1.lastIndexOf(')') === l - 1);
  res = check(str1);
  return res;
}
```

The goal is to check that the first charachter is `(` and the last `)`. Works OK.

```
node mycode.js
true
```

Now, the next step would be the high-order function that would include removing first and last character at each step and checking if the condition is met again.

```
const rec = f => f((...str).slice(1,-1))
```

String befor and after this step.

```
'(()())'
'()()'
```

How to do this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to do this recursively?

Comment: @wxker Fisrt and last removed,again condition should be checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check for length and if the string starts and ends with wanted characters and the rest fullfills the same objective.

```js
const check = string => !string.length || string.startsWith('(') && string.endsWith(')') && check(string.slice(1, -1));

console.log(check('((()))'));
console.log(check('((())'));
```

Comment: Thanks,really nice annswer. But manbe you have idea how to repeat multiple times until 2 charechters are left?